# Correct gauge wire for ev 14-50 installation. Garage is up to 50' from breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, garage, installation

new here.
I've decided to diy my basement bathroom, but before I close it up I wanted to upgrade the electrical.
The garage is very far from the panel (very conservatively 50 ft away, more likely close to 40 ft). Will a 6 gauge wire be sufficient? I'm not sure if I'm reading the voltage drop calculators right etc. I think at the end of the day it will be a GFCI 14-50. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: 50' is not "very far". Don't worry about voltage drop at that distance. What you do need to look at is: copper vs. aluminum, type of wire/cable (individual wires require conduit but may mean using smaller (cheaper) wires, plus conduit provides more upgrade potential), temperature ratings (depends on a bunch of factors, but can definitely affect the wire size requirements), and future upgrades (is an EV charger the *only* think you want to add, or are you considering having tools or other stuff in the garage in the future?)

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I'm not looking at using it for anything other than ev charging. I always thought Copper was better than Aluminum, I think I would rather go over and rest assured that the house is not going to burn down. I was thinking romex 6/3. Some of the 50' will route through the subfloor, and the some I'd protect inside a conduit on finished wall of garage

Comment: Copper is better than aluminum in that a smaller wire will do the job. But that smaller wire is now (at larger sizes like 6 AWG) much more expensive than the equivalent (a size larger) aluminum. If everything is compatible then nothing wrong with aluminum. Standard 15A/20A receptacles are *not* compatible but many larger devices, are.

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks for letting me know! Appreciate it!

Comment: The bad reputation aluminum has is from using a bad alloy with terminals made from material not suited for aluminum that resulted in oxidation. Modern aluminum with devices Listed for aluminum is fine. If you have time see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_building_wiring

Answer (score 3):

There are variables that determine temperature rating of circuit, wire type, wire insulation type, cable/conduit temperature rating, conduit fill or cable grouping, and device (breaker and receptacle) rating. The minimum rating of any component subjects the whole circuit to the minimum rating.

#8 copper THWN in conduit with only a few circuits, and a high quality 75°C you are likely good to go. 60°C receptacle you are going to need #6.

#6 aluminum SE cable you are good to go if you have a 75°C receptacle, if you have a typical retail 60°C receptacle you would need #4 aluminum.

Your specific wiring method and routing could modify the end result.

50 feet is not an issue, the code has built in deratings that easily cover 100'.

Comment: One thing when discussing AL wire is we should always remind people that you need to remember to put the "goop" on the wire before putting in the connection terminal.  That "goop" would be NoAlox compound, available in most hardware stores and certainly electrical supply shops.